# How to access param values in controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got a task to access param values for creating new user.My controller code for create is

```
def newstudent
    @student = Student.new(params)
   puts "+++++++++++"
   puts params.inspect

    if @student.save 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @jtable }
    end
    end
  end
```

But by doing this i had got some error in terminal.It shows like this

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: action, controller):
  app/controllers/students_controller.rb:42:in `new'
  app/controllers/students_controller.rb:42:in `newstudent'
```

Please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: After submitting form controller will call `create` method along with the `id`.so in your case you can do like `@student = Student.find(params[:id])`.if you are creating new record using your method `newstudent` then you can use `@student = Student.new()`.

Comment: I had got the soluton for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my controller for add new student. By getting that error message you must reject controller and action using  `@student = Student.new(params.reject {|key,value| key =="controller" || key =="action"})` code.

```
 def newstudent
        @student = Student.new(params.reject {|key,value| key =="controller" || key =="action"})

        if @student.save 
          @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Record' => @student.attributes}
        else
         @jtable = {'Result' => 'ERROR','Message'=>'Empty'}
        end  
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @jtable }
        end

      end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3.2.3 there is no mass assignment by default. You have to go your model and add attr_accessible :name, :position, :visible. Basically you have to add every attribute you want to mass assign.

```
 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :position, :visible
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Student model should whitelist the attributes that can be mass-assigned using `attr_accessible` as in:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```